# Inversify + Typescript 5: TS1239: Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs, typescript-5

One of my projects uses Inversify for dependency injection like this:

```
@injectable()
export class MyClass {

constructor(
    @inject(OtherClass) private otherClass: OtherClass,
    ...
) {
}
```

This always worked fine and should be OK according to the docs, but when trying to upgrade from TS4 to TS5 it results in the following error (which refers to the line with `constructor(...)`):

```
error TS1239: Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
```

Is there anything that can be done about this or is Inversify no longer usable with TS5? If it's no longer compatible, would there be a drop-in replacement for Inversify?

Comment: I think typescript 5 only supports function decorators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's related with your inversify version.. [inversify@6.0.1 seems to work fine](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52435#issuecomment-1405522045)

But as you can see there is changes in TS5 regarding this matter, [More Accurate Type-Checking for Parameter Decorators in Constructors Under --experimentalDecorators](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52435#issuecomment-1405522045)

keep it strong

Comment: Thanks, that was a really good hint. I didn't notice that my inversify version was still locked to 5.x and upgrading to 6.x did indeed fix it!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realise TypeScript 5 was out, but after seeing your question I upgraded an inversify project of mine and the code worked the same as previously. Eg [this class of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/logic/services/companyService.ts) is similar to yours:

```js
@injectable()
export class CompanyService {

    private readonly _repository: CompanyRepository;
    private readonly _customClaims: SampleCustomClaims;

    public constructor(
        @inject(SAMPLETYPES.CompanyRepository) repository: CompanyRepository,
        @inject(BASETYPES.CustomClaims) customClaims: CustomClaims) {

        this._repository = repository;
        this._customClaims = customClaims as SampleCustomClaims;
    }
```

In my case I use the following tsconfig.json file. I have always needed to use the experimentalDecorators setting, which [still works in TS5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-rc/#differences-with-experimental-legacy-decorators):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module":"ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

So it feels like they remain compatible and you should be able to get your project working by comparing to [my repo](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs). There could be other valid setups that are different to my own though.

Comment: Thanks for your input, experimentalDecorators was already in use.

Answer (score 0):

To add some informations to this, maybe just to clarify why this is working.
`inversify` works with typescript 5 or higher ( as long as you have `experimentalDecorators` ) because when I prepared the [upgrade](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/pull/1407) we made sure to include `string | symbol | undefined` as types for keys, since this "breaking" change was somehow unavoidable. Hope this clarifies a bit what's really happening.